# Prove that a finite union of compact sets is compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, proof-verification

Can you please let me know if my proof is correct? I would like to make sure that I've understood the concept of open covers and subcoverings correctly.

> **Proof**:
>
> Suppose $\Pi = \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n H_k$ is a finite union of $n$ compact sets. Then there is a finite subcovering for every open covering of $H_k$. In particular, if $\Psi_k = \{V_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}^{(k)}$ is an open covering of $H_k$ then $\Psi_{k_0}=\{V_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A_0}^{(k)}$ (where $A_0$ is a finite subset of $A$) is a subcovering of $H_k$. Consider $\Xi = \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n\Psi_{k_0}$, the union of all subcoverings of $H_k$ (for $1\le k\le n$). Then $X$ is an open subcovering of $\Pi$, which implies that $\Pi$ is compact.

Comment: No. You have to start with an open cover of the union. BTW, it suffices to consider only two compact sets. Always simplify in order to understand thigs better.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp: Do you mean I have to start with an open cover for $\Pi$? But I have to derive that there is this open cover by arguing first that there is an open cover for each $H_k$.

Comment: You need to show if you have any open cover of $\Pi$, there is a finite subcover.  That's what it means for $\Pi$ to be compact.  You aren't allowed to start with open covers of the $H_k$.

Comment: @D_S: But how do I know that I have an open cover of $\Pi$? I only know that I have open covers for $H_k$, because I know that they are compact. It's that which I need to prove that $\Pi$ has an open covering. I think I'm totally lost now.

Comment: The whole space is an open cover for $\Pi$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp: what exactly is the flaw in my proof?

Comment: There are no logical errors in your proof as far as I can tell.  However, you didn't prove that $\Pi$ was compact.

Comment: @D_S: I showed that $\Pi$ has a finite subcovering, which is compactness by definition. Maybe I got something wrong, but here's what I read in my textbook:

"A subset $H$ of a metric space $X$ is said to be compact if and only if every open covering of $H$ has a finite subcover".

Comment: Did you show that *every* open covering of $\Pi$ has a finite subcover?

Comment: "I showed that Π has a finite subcovering, which is compactness by definition." Can't you read what we tell you? This is wrong. I repeat: A set is compact if **each** open subcover contains a finite one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with an open cover $(U_\alpha)_{\alpha\in A}$ of $K_1\cup K_2$. Now, is it an open cover of $K_1$? Yes, fine. So, take a finite subcover. Do the same for $K_2$ and take the union of the two finite subcovers (where you cancel those in the second one that already are in the covering of $K_1$).

Comment: How do we know that an open cover of $K_1 \cup K_2$ exists?

Comment: The existence of a specific open cover for $K_1 \cup K_2$ is irrelevant here (if you want one, take just the whole topological space, that's an open cover by one open set).  You need to show that if you begin with *any* open cover of $K_1 \cup K_2$, then it can be reduced to a finite subcover.

Comment: It's not like you can prove compactness by finding an open cover of $K_1 \cup K_2$ and reducing that thing to a finite subcover.

Comment: Correct, since **all** subcovers are supposed to contain a finite one.

Comment: @D_S: so is Friedrich's approach correct or not? I didn't understand it from your comment.

Comment: Of course, it is correct. The thing is you will have to make it more precise. I want you to learn - not to simply copy.

Comment: @sequence Yes Friedrich's approach is correct.  He begins with an *arbitrary* open cover of $K_1 \cup K_2$ and indicates how to reduce it to a finite subcover.  In a few minutes all of this is going to click in your brain haha.  Compactness also confused me and most of my class when we first saw it in real analysis

Comment: So, if $\{U_{\alpha}\}$ is an open cover of $K_1 \cup K_2$ then $K_1 \subset \{U_{\alpha}\}$, thus $\{U_{\alpha}\}$ is an open cover of $K_1$. In particular, since $K_1$ is compact, there exists a finite subcovering $A:= \{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A_0}$ of $K_1$. By similar argument, $B :=\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A_1}$ is an open cover for $K_2$. Hence, $A \cup B$ is a finite subcovering of $K_1 \cup K_2$. Do you think this argument is valid?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. Only one thing: $K_1\subset\{U_\alpha\}$ does not make sense. You mean $K_1\subset\bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha$.